# How to get Gamer ID and display picture?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

Since Google recently added Gamer ID to Google Play Games. How do I acquire this Gamer ID + the associated google provided display picture? I need to use them with SharedPreferences for a function.

Answer (score 0):

**To create a Gamer ID and sign in**

When you sign in to a game on Play Games or the Play Games app itself, you'll be prompted to create a Gamer ID:

1. When you see the prompt, tap **Next**.
2. You'll see a default Gamer ID and photo.

   - To change the Gamer ID, just type over it.
   - To change the photo, tap Edit Google Play pencil icon.
   - You can always change your Gamer ID and photo later.
3. Choose whether to allow others to see your game activity and/or discover your Gamer ID using your email or name.
4. Tap **Sign in**.

Once you're signed in to Play Games with your Gamer ID, you'll be automatically signed in to most of the games you play. You can also change your gamer profile or privacy setting like choosing whether to make your game activity public as also discussed further in [Play games with a Gamer ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2954594?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

There are some APIs.

You can use `Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer` to get current Player object. And `Player` has some functions like `getPlayerId`, `getHiResImageUri` to get the information you want.